# About Schanuel's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, transcendence-theory

If Schanuel's conjecture is true, why does it mean that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebricaly independent?
I just understand that we have $deg.tr_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q} (e,i\pi) \geq 2$.

Comment: $i$ is algebraic, so if $e$ and $i\pi$ are algebraically independent, so are $e$ and $\pi$.

Comment: but why the inequality give us that $e$ and $i \pi$  are algebraically independent ?

Comment: The transcendence degree is the largest number of algebraically independent elements. If $e$ and $i\pi$ were algebraically dependent, then everything else in the field, being rational expressions in $e$ and $i\pi$, would also be algebraically dependent with, say, $e$, so there would be no two algebraically dependent elements, and the transcendence degree woiuld be one.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer it's very clear now ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the field $F=\mathbb{Q}(1,e^1,i\pi,e^{i\pi})$. Because $e^{i\pi}=-1$, $F=\mathbb{Q}(1,e,i\pi,-1)$.

$1$ and $i\pi$ are complex numbers that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Schanuel's conjecture then gives trdeg$(F/\mathbb{Q})\ge 2$. $1$ and $-1$ are algebraic, $i$ is algebraic. Therefore the set $\{e,\pi\}$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.